# Getting GUID of Action Map in Unitys New Input System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

I am starting to delve into using multiple action maps in Unity's new input system to better separate the input for different parts of my game. I am currently working on creating the logic for changing the active action map at runtime, and as part of this, I am hoping to get a reference to the action maps that I have created on my InputActionAsset.

Looking into the documentation for action maps, I saw that these action maps can be referred to using a string matching its name, or with a GUID for the action map. I tend to avoid using string references as much as possible as I want to ability to rename these action maps in the future without breaking my logic, but I am having a hard time finding any resources describing how to get the GUID of these action maps outside of a hacky workaround.

One way that I have found to get these GUIDs is to set the DefaultMap of the PlayerInput component to the desired action map, then have a temporary MonoBehaviour print the GUID using:

```
[SerializeField] private PlayerInput _playerInput;

private void Awake()
{
    Debug.Log(_playerInput.currentActionMap.id);
}
```

but this feels very hacky and I would need to repeat this for every action map I create in the future. I am assuming that there is a better way of getting these GUIDs directly but from everything I've tried so far I have been unable to find it. Does anybody know of a way of doing this?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: well each part has an ID, so it makes reasonable sense.. if you look in the c# file generated all the IDs are in it

Comment: You can loop through all the action maps (from your PlayerInput) and get the id for each one.  Its not clear why you need to print the id.  The way you show above IS how you get the id.

Comment: @hijinxbassist That method would definitely work for simply retrieving all of the IDs, but I am hoping to get specific IDs for certain action maps and use them as constants so that during runtime I can dynamically change which action map is active, so I'm needing a way of differentiating them other than by their names. I ended up finding what I was looking for but thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the ideal implementation I was hoping for thanks to advice from @derHugo. As per their recommendation, if you generate a C# class for the InputActionAsset, all you need to do is create an instance of this C# class during runtime and then use that reference for accessing any data about action maps.

```
private void Awake()
{
    InGameInputAction inGameInputAction = new InGameInputAction();
    InputActionMap characterInputActionMap = inGameInputAction.CharacterInputActionMap;
}
```

This is exactly the functionality that I was hoping for and completely removes the need to access GUIDs at all.

Thank you again @derHugo for pointing this out to me, it has saved a lot of unnecessary manual caching of GUIDs and things are much cleaner now!

I would love for this information to be available somewhere more easily accessible in Unity's documentation of the new input system, as this was not very obvious to me, and though I spent a decent amount of time searching for this functionality I ended up assuming that using GUIDs was the only way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this in the future, the answer was more straightforward than I thought, but I still find it strange that there was no mention of this in the Unity documentation.

To find the GUID's for Action Maps, as well as Input Actions, you must first select the InputActionAsset in the project view, and then in the inspector make sure that the "Generate C# Class" box is checked.

[Generate C# Class option for InputActionAsset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iwv6.png)

You then simply need to open the C# class that was created for this InputActionAsset, and within that file it will have the GUIDs for the action maps.

Thank you to @BugFinder for pointing me in the right direction, I now have the functionality that I was hoping for!

Comment: But if you generate the `c#` class there is no reason whatsoever to go through the GUID ... simply go through e.g. `playerInput.UIActionMap.SomeUIAction`, `playerInput.CameraActionMap.SomeCameraAction` etc .. replacing of course with your own action map and action names

Comment: @derHugo Thank you so much for your response, it never occurred to me to get a reference of the generated c# class but that makes so much sense and works exactly the way I was hoping for. I added a new answer including this information. Thanks for your help!